# Jackson-annotation 2.2.3 not generating getter. How to print value of enum?

Tags: java, enums, jackson

Jackson-annotation 2.2.3 not generating getter.
    I want to print value of 
    enum FOOTBALL as FOOT BALL but not able to print. 
    what is the solution? Below is the generated code using JAckson-annotation2.2.3 jar

```
public enum Sports{
      @JsonProperty("FOOTBALL")
      FOOTBALL("FOOT BALL"), //enum value

      @JsonProperty("BasketBALL")
      BasketBALL("Basket BALL"),

      private String name;

      DisbMethodCode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```

Comment: How is this supposed to work within an `enum`?

Comment: `name` is public, why do you need a getter?

Comment: I am sorry the name is private. i corrected it